# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split')

Tags: node.js, heroku, devops

I was deploying my mern stack app to heroku, getting some kind of errors screenshot attached.

errors from activity logs:
2022-09-08T22:02:02.914114+00:00 app[web.1]: app is running at 35635
2022-09-08T22:02:02.914778+00:00 app[web.1]: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split')
2022-09-08T22:02:03.072495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-09-08T22:02:03.137611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-09-08T22:06:33.637723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/products" host=spiffy-shirts.herokuapp.com request_id=c6a06345-ab6b-4dbf-a76b-212dc9d9e81e fwd="27.4.164.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

[image]

In my local env everything works fine.

My server index file code

```js
// dependancy included: express,mongosse,cors,bodyParser, cookieParser ...
const app = express();

//DB
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });

    console.log('MongoDB is Connected...');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
connectDB();

//My routes
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');

//Middlewares
//bodyparser, cookieparser,cors ...

//PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 6000;

//My routes
app.use('/api', authRoutes);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('frontend/build'));
}

//Starting a Server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app is running at ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: The snippet you included does not mention any use of "split". The error likely occurred in another file other to the one you've posted. Consider uploading your API files and checking where they used "split"

Answer (score 0):

It was an internal error of mongoURI, I just removed double quotes"" from uri it works great